# Windows 8 XAML Apps - C++ vs C# - User Experience Differences

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

Are there any scenarios where the user experience of a Windows 8 XAML app would be different depending on whether it was developed in C# or C++ (i.e. managed vs native).

For example, if the app had a `GridView` bound to 500 or so data items via a complex `DataTemplate` that included `IValueConverters` etc would one language/technology perform better than the other from a users point of view ?

Im trying to establish whether to use C++ or C# for a fairly complex, data-heavy Windows store XAML app that needs to run well on both ARM and X86/X64 architectures.

**EDIT**

Here is a clarification of my question:

Are there any scenarios where the user experience of a Windows 8 XAML app would be different (if any) depending on whether it was **developed to run with a managed CLR, or written to run in the native environment**

**EDIT 2**

OK - forget about coding style. Its very easy to create C# (managed) and C++ (unmanaged) apps that look almost exactly the same and let us assume that for the purpose of this question there are no implementation differences.

1. The code is similar enough to be irrelevant
2. You have at least 500 data items
3. You have a GridView
4. You have a Complex DataTemplate in you ItemTemplate (the same template in both scenarios)

Question - would the user experience be the same. Does anyone have an answer, or do I have to write all the code and try it myself ????

Comment: What would de development language have to do with this? "fairly complex" and "data-heavy" are to vague to get good answers. When worried about performance: TEST

Comment: The development language has everything to do with it, as one will produce a managed executable and the other an unmanaged executable

Comment: Speed hardly ever depends on the programming language. It rather depends on the programming skills of the designer/programmer.

Comment: But a c++ XAML app will run on different technology than a C# one - that is my point (i.e c++ wont be running on a CLR etc)

Comment: That doesn't mean it will be faster by definition.

Comment: You are not understanding the question, as perhaps i have written it a little clumsily, but the key is managed vs native performance in XMAL apps - what are the performance differences (if any)

Comment: I am afraid you do not understand my answer. It is impossible to give you a general answer because your implementation will be different. Implement a key scenario in both languages and test.

Comment: I think that it's likely that there will be differences between languages/frameworks but those differences pale  before the differences between an efficient implementation and a bad implementation. If you really want to choose on performance, get some numbers.

Comment: I understand what Emo is saying, but that doesnt relate to my question. My question is about the underlying technology that runs Windows 8 store apps. It is my fault for not making it clearer at the outset in my question

Comment: If you need to squeeze the most performance possible out of your app, then C++ is what you're looking for.  That being said, 99.99% of apps don't actually need that, so unless you have an app that is far outside of normal, the thing you should look to optimize is your design rather than the language you choose.

Comment: thanks mydogisbox - but do you have any information to back up your claim. Its not that I dont believe you, its just that XAML apps are complex beasts from a technology point of view, and I suspect they behave differently depending on wether they run native or managed

Comment: The answer is easy as that - if you have a choice, write in a language you are familiar the best to produce the better code possible. I believe, 99,99% of us would do this. This is not a selection of language for embedded systems where C/C++ will always win.

Comment: Unless you test your scenario yourself you will never know. From my experience coding in C# tends to be 10 times faster than in C++, so you can spend the remaining 90% of that time optimizing but of course YMMV. Of course C++ is faster so if you code the same things the same way in both languages - the C++ version will run faster, but at the cost of longer development time and costlier maintenance. I agree with Wilbert that you should not optimize prematurely. You can always make part of the code use C++ if you find it helpful.

Comment: Nice comment Filip, Im just try to establish if C++ would be faster in my proposed scenatio - all other things being equal. If C# is 10% slower then I would still develop and optimise in C#

Answer (score 5):

It will not depend on C# vs. C++.

Windows XAML is heavily GPU-dependent, and, assuming you use reasonably written code with algorithms with a good enough time complexity, both a C# and a C++ app will behave with similar performance on all tasks related to the UI.

Time will either be spent updating GPU buffers, or somewhere in the windows or XAML libraries - not anywhere the language you choose will have an impact.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, but Im wondering if hopping in and out of managed code within your ValueConverters or DataTemplateSelectors will make a difference on the Rendering thread

Comment: No, it won't. Don't worry about this kind of stuff beforehand. Premature optimization and all...

Comment: Im still not convinced that code that is hopping continuously between the managed and unmanaged world wont have an impact. DataBindings rely on the performance of the binding mechanisms. A non-databound XAML app would definitely be unaffected, but when you add data that lives in the CLR world into the mix, Im not so sure you are right

Comment: I would hope that unless your data changes constantly - you won't see a difference between C++/C#.

Comment: But if you use IValueConverter and DataTemplateSelector then your data WILL have to be evaluated constantly

Answer (score 3):

500 items in a ListView is tending toward the large side. Most of the code that's taking processor time is going to be the Windows Runtime, rendering the UI and dealing with scrolling and such; and both C# and C++ use the exact same UI runtime. The amount of CPU time spent on your own code will probably be insignificant by comparison. Your optimization efforts will mostly involve paying attention to how you define your item templates, enabling virtualization, etc.

So the implementation language will probably matter very little to your app's performance. Choose whichever language you can develop in most effectively.

Comment: C# and C++ XAML both run native, but on the C# scenario you'll be carrying around the CLR with you, and if you have things like IValueConverters and DataTemplateSelectors running in the CLR your going to be hopping over the managed/unmanaged boundry a lot. Im trying to find out how significant that would be

Comment: A 500 items ListView should be virtualized anyway, so the converters and template selectors should only run for items that are visible.